# Same sub-folder names for python imports

Tags: python, python-import

- I'm working on a collection of **python scripts** for daily work.
- To avoid duplication, we want to make use of **import** to share some tools.
- To keep the `repository maintainable`, we have **sub-folders to collect scripts for specific purposes** and a `lib-folder` in each sub-folder to keep the shared functions.

The structure looks like this.

```
root
├── lib
│   ├── hello.py
└── sub
    ├── hello_user.py
    └── lib

__init__.py files exist, but are filtered for better readability
```

The code in hello_user.py is this:

```
from lib.hello import hello
hello()
```

and in hello.py:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello")
```

- **PYTHONPATH** is set to the `root folder`.
- When I try to execute "python sub/hello_user.py", I get an error "ImportError: No module named hello". If I rename sub/lib to sub/lib_hide, I get the expected output "Hello".
- How do i get python to import from **root/lib** instead of **root/sub/lib**?
- Setting `PYTHONPATH to "root/.."` and `importing "root.lib"` would work but is probably not a viable option (would require changes in all setups using the scripts and in all existing scripts).
- I'd prefer a solution where I just modify the `import statement`. Relative path would be fine, but how would I name a `relative path` to a parent folder? "..".**lib.hello** does not work.

Comment: __init__ file exists but where do they exist? Readability is good, information is better ;)

Comment: __init__.py exists in each of the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If execute the script using `python sub/hello_user.py`, then the directory `sub` is automatically added to `sys.path` as first element. Therefore `root/sub/lib` will be found before `root/lib` and therefore hide it, no matter where `PYTHONPATH` points. The only way to change this would be to make sure `root` appears before `root/sub` in the path:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '.../root')
```

If you import the module (or execute the module directly by using `python -m sub.hello_user`) then the situation is different.

In python2, the import is implicitly regarded as relative, so it will try to import `root/sub/lib/hello.py`, `root/lib` is again shadowed by `root/sub/lib`.

Python3 fixes this by making imports absolute by default, so it would import `root/lib/hello.py`. You can get this behaviour in python2 by adding `from __future__ import absolute_import`:

```
# root/sub/hello_user.py:

from __future__ import absolute_import
from lib import hello      # imports root/lib/hello.py
from sub.lib import hello  # imports root/sub/lib/hello.py
from .lib import hello     # same, but relative import instead of absolute
```

However this will still only work if `sub` isn't in the path earlier then `root`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try inserting your roor/lib folder to sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'complete/path/root/lib')
```

sys.path is a "list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default" (from http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.path#sys.path).

Two comments: it's recommended to do leave sys.path[0] untouched (hence the 1) because the first (0) being the current folder is expected behavior. Second, there is sys.path.append which will add the desired path to the *end* of sys.path (not what you want).

There is also the imp lib ray (http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp) which might be of use.

Hope it helps,
P

Comment: Thanks, I think this is helpful. Especially the imp library looks useful on a first glance, will see if it solves our problems.